# Jquery div jumps when page loaded

Tags: jquery

Okay I'll try to make this question more understandable.... here goes. I'm currently using JQuery animations on my website. The animations work fine; however, when the page is refreshed the divs containing the animation jump around before they position themselves in the right location. Sometimes the divs will even load at a different vertical position (it then stays this way until the cursor is hovered over the image/div. The divs with the problem are the row1 and row2 divs. This problem seems to occur mostly in Chrome. I'm looking for a way to get the jump to stop and get the div to load in the right location 100% of the time.

this problem occurs on this page of my site:  http://derektice.com/pages/fourthyear.html

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>

    <head>
        <title>PORTFOLIO || Derek Tice</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="../stylesheets/global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="../stylesheets/fourthyear.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../stylesheets/fourthyear.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
      window.onload = function()
      {
          init();
      };
</script>
    </head>
        <div style="width:1px; height:1px; visibility:hidden; overflow:hidden">
            <img src="../images/nav_bar/home-hover.png" />
            <img src="../images/nav_bar/about-hover.png" />
            <img src="../images/nav_bar/contact-hover.png" />
            <img src="../images/nav_bar/downloads-hover.png" />
            <img src="../images/nav_bar/fourthyear-hover.png" />
            <img src="../images/nav_bar/thirdyear-hover.png" />
            <img src="../images/nav_bar/secondyear-hover.png" />
            <img src="../images/nav_bar/extra-hover.png" />
        </div>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="titleblock">
                <a href="../index.html"><img src="../images/title.png"></a>
                <div id="navigation">
                    <a href="../index.html" class="home"></a>
                    <a href="about.html" class="about"></a>     
                    <a href="contact.html" class="contact"></a>
                    <a href="downloads.html" class="downloads"></a>
                        <p>
                    <a href="fourthyear.html"><img src="../images/nav_bar/fourthyear-hover.png"></a>
                    <a href="thirdyear.html" class="third"></a>
                    <a href="secondyear.html" class="second"></a>
                    <a href="extra.html" class="extra"></a>     
                </div>
                <div id="content">
                    <div id="row1">                         
                        <div class="img-wrap">                          
                            <div class="scraperfilter"></div>
                            <a href="skyscraper.html"><div class="overlay"></div></a>                       
                            <a href="skyscraper.html"><img src="../images/skyscraper.png"/></a>
                            <div id="text1"></div>
                        </div>                  
                    </div>
                    <div id="row2">                     
                        <div class="img-wrap">  
                            <div class="busbarnfilter"></div>
                            <div class="overlay"></div>                         
                            <a href="busbarn.html"><img src="../images/busbarn.png"/></a>
                            <div id="text2"></div>
                        </div>                  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="copyright">
                Copyright &#169 2013  ||  All rights reserved
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

**corresponding css**

```
body{
    width:1012px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    text-align:left;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#c9c9c9;
    margin-top:0px;
}

a img{
    border:none;
}

#container{
    width:1012px;
    height:423px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    top:15%;
    position:absolute;
}

#titleblock{
    width:200px;
    height:403px;
    background-color:#4a4a4a;
    opacity:.95;
}

#content{
    width:809px;
    height:403px;
    margin-left:203px;
    margin-top:-37px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:;
}

#navigation{
    width:195px;
    height:173px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:15px;
    padding-left:5px;
}

#copyright{
    width:1002px;
    height:20px;
    margin-top:2px;
    padding-left:7px;
    text-align:left;
}


 #row1{
    width:200px;
    height:403px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:0px;
    position:absolute;
 }

 #text1{
    width:200px;
    height:203px;
    background-image:url('../images/skyscraper-text.png');
    margin-top:0px;
    position:relative;
    cursor:default; 
}

#row2{
    width:200px;
    height:403px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    display:inline-block;
    z-index:20;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:203px;
}

#text2{
    width:200px;
    height:203px;
    background-image:url('../images/busbarn-text.png');
    margin-top:0px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:30;
    cursor:default;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function () {

  $('.img-wrap')
  .mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).find('.overlay').stop().animate({top:"203px"}, 200);
  })
  .mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find('.overlay').stop().animate({top: 0}, 300);
  });

  $('.img-wrap2')
  .mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).find('.overlay2').stop().animate({top:"203px"}, 200);
  })
  .mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find('.overlay2').stop().animate({top: 0}, 300);
  });


});
```

Comment: Can you post some code instead of just a link?

Comment: @ user: MOre on PinnyM's request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Answer (score 0):

This is usually the result of margins on an animated item.  What you can do instead is to give the outer div a padding equal to the margin of the inner item, then remove the margin on the inner item.